# how to get two tables data using session in sql after login, but I use 1 table data for login

Tags: php, mysql

```
user{
    email PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    password,
    phone_no,
    user_type_id
}
student{
    email PRIMARY KEY,
    date_of_birth,
    address,
    course_id,
    subject_id
}
examiner{
    email PRIMARY KEY,
    course_id,
    subject_id
}
```

I used email and password from 'user' table to login.
**login_action.php**

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)
or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//To allocate values into session
$_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];
$_SESSION['password']=$row['password'];
$_SESSION['user_type_id']=$row['user_type_id'];
$_SESSION['phone_no']=$row['phone_no'];
if($row['user_type_id'] == 1){
    header("Location:student_dashboard.php");
}else if($row['user_type_id'] == 2){
    header("Location:examiner_dashboard.php");
}
```

Then after login I want Student and Examiner profile details. Then how can I get all details from two tables.

Comment: In `student_dashboard.php` you can write a logic with session of user_type_id in where clause.

Comment: $sql="SELECT u.email, u.password, u.phone_no, u.user_type_id, e.first_name first_name, e.last_name last_name FROM user u LEFT JOIN examiner e ON u.email=e.email WHERE WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."' AND user_type_id='".$_SESSION['user_type_id']."' ";
  
  //$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."' AND user_type_id='".$_SESSION['user_type_id']."'; ";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  
  ?>

Comment: what is the error? Please format you question with this comment.

Comment: I used above sql , then the error is  "there is an error 'Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in G:\xampp\htdocs\examination_system\src\examiner\examiner_profile.php on line 111'

Comment: first of all remove one 'WHERE WHERE ' where from statement. Make sure that `$dbcon` has established connection.

Comment: ok Thank You!   Its work.

Comment: When I login to the examiner and student using two browser tabs, the profile details are changed. 1st I login to examiner then display profile details of examiner. next I login student using another email it views student profile , but previous tab in examiner profile also change and preview student details.... Why is that?

Comment: Yes its because you are access both from one session. Clear the session after use

Comment: Can u exapalin it plz, how to clear the session? and which page should i clear the session? I want open examiner dashboard and student dashboard in two tabs in same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, remove one 'WHERE WHERE ' where from statement.